# Gluon Scene Builder 8.3.0 - FXML fails to load when contain fx:include

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, gluon, gluon-mobile

Part of my FXML file contains the code at the end of this thread. It seems that the new Scene Builder (8.3.0) does not support the < fx:include/> part, cause when I try to open the FXML file it returns the following exception.

```
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/D:/workspace/javafx/src/SearchScreen.fxml:159

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.load(FXOMLoader.java:89)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.TransientIntrinsic cannot be cast to com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.TransientObject
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.fxom.FXOMLoader.endElement(FXOMLoader.java:315)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2826)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    ... 52 more
```

When I comment out the < fx:include/> part, then the FXML opens just fine in the Scene Builder. I remember that one of the previous versions of Scene Builder did not have this problem. Is there any link with the previous versions available for download?

```
<fx:include fx:id="searchPane" source="newSearch/SearchPane.fxml" style="-fx-border-color: white; -fx-background-color: white; -fx-background: white;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8">
        <GridPane.margin>
                <Insets right="10.0" />
        </GridPane.margin>
</fx:include>
```

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I downloaded all the previous versions from the link below, and none fix it. So, I am not sure now which version I had before that was working OK with.

https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/downloads/?tab=tags

Comment: Check to see if it's a bug. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087662

Comment: OpenJDK does not manage Scene Builder bugs - those are managed [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues?status=new&status=open).

Comment: Scene Builder does support `fx:include`. Can you post what's failing for you? At least something we can reproduce.